# Parallax scrolling opacity issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parallax

I am coding my page so that the content fades in and out as you scroll.

when you scroll away from the "trilogy" section, then scroll back up, it is not 100% opacity when at the top again.

Also the content fades out half way the trilogy section, then fades back in again.  I need the content when at the top (minus the green header area) to be 100% opacity when in view.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(window).bind('scroll', function(e) {
    setParalaxContent();
});

function setParalaxContent() {

 var trilogy = {
    scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop(),
    windowHeight: $(window).height(),
    contentTop: $('.trilogy2').position().top,
    contentHeight:2200  
};

// determine scrollTop's bounds where content enters & exits the window
trilogy.lowerBound = trilogy.contentTop - trilogy.windowHeight;
trilogy.upperBound = trilogy.contentTop + trilogy.contentHeight;
// determine scrollTop's position percentage (x2) in relation to bounds
trilogy.percent = (trilogy.scrollTop - trilogy.lowerBound) /     (trilogy.upperBound - trilogy.lowerBound) * 2;

}

$('.trilogy2').animate({
    opacity: 1 - Math.abs(trilogy.percent - 1)
}, 1);
```

Please see full code at:
http://jsfiddle.net/warrior_76/pnr4fdyg/

Comment: Open your javascript console (CTRL + SHIFT + K in Firefox), and run this: http://jsfiddle.net/AndreaLigios/pnr4fdyg/1/ . You will see that the math is a bit different from what you think. Good luck with that BTW